# SVN Check out from a IP

Tags: php, svn

I want to checkout a code repository from an IP which is mapped to dev server SVN directory.

So it is like whenever i hit the ip XX.XX.XXX.XX it is redirected to a directory in my dev server : ~/code/svn_dir

When i try to checkout using iTerminal using the syntax given below i am getting an error:

```
me@my-MBP ~/Dev/NewCode $  svn co --username user1 http://XX.XX.XXX.XX
```

Errors:

```
svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://XX.XX.XXX.XX'
svn: E175002: The OPTIONS request returned invalid XML in the response: XML parse error at line 1: no element found (http://XX.XX.XXX.XX)
```

Another try:

```
svn co --username letterbanc http://XX.XX.XXX.XX/web
Redirecting to URL 'http://XX.XX.XXX.XX/web':
Redirecting to URL 'http://XX.XX.XXX.XX/web':
svn: E195019: Redirect cycle detected for URL 'http://XX.XX.XXX.XX/web'
```

Another Try:

```
svn co XX.XX.XXX.XX
svn: E205000: Try 'svn help' for more info
svn: E205000: Error parsing arguments
```

Also, SVN client is configured and working for other checkouts from my directories. SVN version in iterminal shows:

```
svn --version
svn, version 1.7.10 (r1485443)

   compiled Aug 13 2013, 15:31:22
```

Answer (score 0):

> svn co --username user1 http://XX.XX.XXX.XX

You can't checkout from `SVNParentPath`, only from real repository-root

> svn co --username letterbanc http://XX.XX.XXX.XX/web

SVN-part of Apache-config is wrong (I'm not a sensitive, but I'll predict) - it seems Apache have "real" directory `/web` under web-root and the same name used in `<Location>` for SVN. It's bad and wrong

Comment: if you see above i have done that and this one gives me cycle detected error

Comment: @CodeMonkey - if you see above i have answer on this trouble